# Encrypting a struct, bad data error, what's causing that?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, the encryption it seems to work but when you get to the decryption says bad data when trying to deserialize it, not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm new at doing encryption so if it's something really simple I'm sorry.

```
    public byte[] Serialize(object obj, string key)
    {
        byte[] returnBytes;
        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider crypt = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] pass = provider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            crypt.Key = pass;
            crypt.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            crypt.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(memory, crypt.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
                stream.Close();
                memory.Close();
            }

            returnBytes = memory.ToArray();
        }

        return returnBytes;
    }
    public object Deserialize(byte[] inBytes, string key)
    {
        object returnObj;
        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider crypt = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] pass = provider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            crypt.Key = pass;
            crypt.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            crypt.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(memory, crypt.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                returnObj = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                stream.Close();
                memory.Close();
            }
            return returnObj;
        }

    }
```

This code i did a while back works on strings

```
        public string encrypt(string message, string password)
        {
            byte[] result;
            UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] key = provider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(password));
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider algorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            algorithm.Key = key;
            algorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            byte[] data = UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            try
            {
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = algorithm.CreateEncryptor();
                result = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
            finally
            {
                algorithm.Clear();
                provider.Clear();
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
        }
        public string decrypt(string message, string passsword)
        {
            byte[] result;
            UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] key = provider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(passsword));
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider algorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            algorithm.Key = key;
            algorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(message);
            try
            {
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = algorithm.CreateDecryptor();
                result = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
            finally
            {
                algorithm.Clear();
                provider.Clear();
            }
            return UTF8.GetString(result);
        }
```

Comment: in the `Deserialize()` method shouldn't it be `new MemoryStream(inBytes)`?

Comment: i tried adding the inBytes to the memorystream didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not setting the [`IV`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.iv.aspx) property of `crypt`, so it's starting off as a random value each time. You need to set it to the same value when decrypting as when encrypting - like a salt for hashing. EDIT: Given the way ECB works, it looks like the IV may be ignored, which is why your previous code worked without storing it.

EDIT: While the IV part is certainly required for non-ECB, it's not enough. I'm not sure what the rest of the problem is, although:

- The ECB cipher mode isn't recommended - any reason for using it?
- You may well end up running into problems due to padding; I don't know if `BinaryFormatter` handles that for you automatically, but it's worth looking into.

EDIT: Doh - I've worked out the bigger problem; you should indeed be using `inBytes`, as per Elian's comment. Currently you're completely ignoring the cipher-text - that's got *no* chance of working!

Here's a complete program showing the whole thing hanging together:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        byte[] data = Serialize("Some arbitrary test data", "pass");
        object x = Deserialize(data, "pass");
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }

    private static SymmetricAlgorithm CreateCryptoServiceProvider(string key)
    {
        byte[] passwordHash;
        using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            // It's not clear why you're taking the hash of the password...
            passwordHash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        }
        var crypt = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        crypt.Key = passwordHash;
        crypt.Mode = CipherMode.CBC; // This is the default anyway - can remove
        crypt.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7; // Ditto
        // Fix this to use a randomly generated one and store it for real code.
        crypt.IV = new byte[crypt.BlockSize / 8];
        return crypt;
    }

    public static byte[] Serialize(object obj, string key)
    {
        var provider = CreateCryptoServiceProvider(key);

        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(
                memory, provider.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
            }
            return memory.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static object Deserialize(byte[] inBytes, string key)
    {
        var provider = CreateCryptoServiceProvider(key);

        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(inBytes))
        {
            using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(
                memory, provider.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                return formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @user1216963: What did you set it *to* though?

Comment: When I Serialized the object i saved the got the random IV created then I used that when Deserializing

Comment: @user1216963: Okay, that's reasonable. I'm seeing the same thing (using a zero IV for simplicity). Will look into it a bit more when I get time.

Comment: Thanks I will check in every once and a while looking to see if you or anyone else figure it out

Comment: Im using what im using because of examples iv seen. I have used what this to encrypt string and it works

Comment: I just posted some old code i did that works on strings and it uses the ECB and the padding and no IV and it works

Comment: @user1216963: Okay, it looks like using ECB the IV may be ignored... at the cost of security.

Comment: @user1216963: See my edit for an example of the whole thing working.

Comment: Can you maybe put up an example cause even when i put the inBytes in the memorystream it doesnt work. also what would you suggest on the mode?

edit* lol nvm